# How to compare TortoiseSVN project from different Repositories

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn

I have a c# project that I migrated from VS2010 to VS2015.

Each VS version of project had it's own Repository entry.

I want to compare current to a version from old repository - is this possible?

My structure is:

```
 C:\Repositories\ProjectA
 C:\Repositories\ProjectA_OLD
```

Is there a way to do this within VisualSVN?

If not, I could unix "diff" the inidivdual .cs files IF I new where the old version ones are stored. When I look in C:\Repositories\ProjectA_OLD, I don't see a "trunk" I just see:

```
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None   0 Jun 18 05:59 locks
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None   0 Jun 18 05:59 hooks
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators None 251 Jun 18 05:59 README.txt
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None   0 Jun 18 05:59 conf
-r-xr-x---+ 1 Administrators None   2 Jun 18 05:59 format
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None   0 Nov  4 05:34 db
```

Where are the previous versions of files?